# network interfaces configure for Hokuyo ust 10lx

Tags: ros, ethernet, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I have a Hokuyo ust 10LX LRF, which use ethernet RJ45 connector, rather than USB.

Sequence listed below:

Step 1. Use  10LX's default setting , 192.168.0.10 as LiDAR IP address.

Step 2. Set network.

$ sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0

allow-hotplug eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.0.15

netmask 255.255.255.0

Step 3. Power on LiDAR with 12V@1000mA power supply,

Step 4. Plug RJ45 connector into PC's ethernet port.

Step 5. However get errors saying 'Destination Host Unreachable'.

$ ping 192.168.0.15

64 bytes from 192.168.0.15: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms

64 bytes from 192.168.0.15: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms ...

ping PC okay, but fail to LiDAR:

$ ping 192.168.0.10

PING 192.168.0.10 (192.168.0.10) 56(84) bytes of data.

From 192.168.0.15 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

From 192.168.0.15 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

From 192.168.0.15 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable ...

Thanks very much for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259685/network--interfaces-configure-for-hokuyo-ust-10lx/) by [dehou14](https://answers.ros.org/users/30090/dehou14/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the output of `ip route` and make sure that there is a route going to the 192.168.0.0/24 block using eth0.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1